# Pixel art of a house appears when using camera in virtual android

Tags: android, android-studio, camera, android-emulator, android-camera

[image]

In a virtual android setup you're supposed to be able to navigate through a virtual room when using the camera. In that room, you can change your wall and table arts by uploading images. However, When using certain apps like snapchat, instagram and whatsapp, you get the above pixel art of a green house that's jitters around slightly.

The fact that this same images appears for both snapchat and instagram makes me think that this video is somewhere on the emulated device, and therefore we can change and edit it. and if not, can I still go into that virtual room or upload any images to the camera?

Answer (score 2):

In your AVD configuration, check that your back camera is set to "VirtualScene" instead of emulated. You can find it by clicking on "Advanced Settings".

[image: Example AVD configuration]